# How to call WCF webservice using PhoneGap which returns SOAP object?

Tags: android, cordova

Can anyone tell me,
How to call WCF webservice using PhoneGap/HTML5/Jquery which returns SOAP object?
I want to call WCF service from phonegap application.

Answer (score 0):

try this. may be this will help you.becouse i have done webservices u using this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

       $(function () {
           var url = "http://localhost/newed/WebService.asmx/GetList?format=json";
           $.ajax({
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               url: url,
               dataType: "jsonp",
               success: function (r) {
                   var i = 0;
                   for (i = 0; i < r.d.length; i++) {
                       alert(r.d[i]["firstName"].toString());

                   }
               },

               error: function (xr, msg, e) { debugger; alert(e); }
           });
       });
```